# Проблема с выводом записей(стандартных) WP

Tags: wordpress

Есть страница с произвольным шалбоном, в этом шаблоне делаю вывод всех постов WP
Вывод делаю через `WP-Query();`

```
$args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post'
                'posts_per_page' => 8
        );
$q = new WP_Query($args);
 if($q->have_posts()):
        while($q->have_posts()):
$q->the_post();
///html post
endwhile;
endif;
```

Проблема в том что я получаю всегда только одну запись.

```
'posts_per_page' => -1
```

тоже писал, проблема не ушла.
Вот сама страница с проблемой
[линк](http://dsb02.webazex.beget.tech/nashi-stati/)
Если в настройках WP делаю эту страницу - страницей вывода записей - все выводится, но мне нужно перед выводом еще отфильтровать записи по датам, рубрикам, и т.д., поэтому этот вариант не рассматриваю.

Comment: У вас там `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''posts_per_page'' `, вы запятую пропустили, в примере тоже. Если делаете эту страницу страницей записей, выводится потому что там применяется другой шаблон, для страниц записей и отрабатывает стандартный цикл.

Comment: поправлено, просто опечатка, проблема осталась

Comment: Судя по карточкам которые вам там выводит, у вас судя по всему и не Post выводит, а главную страницу. Вы там случайно в теме ничего не делаете на `pre_get_posts`? И я не совсем понял, что вам мешает сделать фильтрацию на странице вывода записей?

Comment: post type поправил уже, теперь там post, касательно фильтрации на странице записи - какой шаблон мне создавать в таком случае?

Comment: Вам не нужно создавать отдельный шаблон для этого, это будет index.php вашей темы. Немного больше о иерархии шаблонов можете почитать [тут](https://wp-kama.ru/id_7654/ierarhiya-fajlov-temy-shablona.html)

Comment: читал уже, в данном случае мне скорее всего придется использовать get_template_part(), но в таком случае я с большой вероятностью не смогу редактировать контент на этой странице, через админку. Мне надо сделать вывод на этой странице которая сейчас, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем желающим, проблема была тривиальна.
Было:

```
$html = 'какой-то хтмл для статьи';
echo $html;
```

Надо было:

```
$html = '';
//start loop...
$html .= 'какой-то хтмл для статьи';
echo $html;
//end loop
```

Банальная усталость и невнимательность.